# Populate a ACF Select Dropdown from Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to populate an Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Select Dropdown - options - with all the posts within a specific Custom Post Type (PCT)?

Thanks in advance, Ian.

Comment: Yes. [Have you seen their documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/filters/acfload_field/)? Show us what code you have and where you are having a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Milo but I think Nathan's answer below is what I'm after as I'd like ACF to do the hard work ;o)

Comment: If you want to use a Select field rather than a Post Object, you can use this: http://www.weareconvoy.com/2014/01/05/populating-acf-select-fields-with-post-type-values/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you’re looking for this field: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/post-object/

It should allow you to choose any registered custom post type.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I believe this is what I need to start with.